# Passing paramenters and receiving the output of a EXE in ASP pages

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, exe

I have two EXE files , one for encryption and other for decryption.
Now i want to call these exe's in my ASP pages built in VB script to encrypt these values and save then in a file.
These exe's take two or three values as parameters and return two values in XML form.

for exapmle :
Calling exe :: c:\IKish\Shared\Encrypt>Encrypt.exe /iv:"xx xx xx" /text:user

Output ::

```
 <Evalue>
   <key>784cjidbdk77fkdl161c</key>
   <Result>9kflo53jvo1ce4801kskbf399b7</Result>
 </Evalue>
```

Could someone pls help me with the code to execute the exe and catch its output in the ASP file?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set oShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = oShell.Exec("Encrypt.exe /iv:""xx xx xx"" /text:user")
If Not (oExec Is Nothing) Then 
    strOutput = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
End If
```